# Creating a linked list in a for loop with malloc always returns the same address

Tags: c, for-loop, linked-list, malloc

I am creating a linked list with a for loop and doing malloc inside the for loop. The problem I got is inside the for loop, `malloc` always returns the same memory address!

I thought it should return a different address every iteration so that I can link the nodes. The current output means the program is always overwriting the same address and I cannot link the nodes, because there is only one node all the time. Is it correct?

```
struct list_node {
    char *id;
    char *url;
    struct list_node *next;
};
int main(void) {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        struct list_node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
        printf("No %d has address %p\n", j, &new_node);
    }
}

=> 
No 0 has address 0x7fff5db122b0
No 1 has address 0x7fff5db122b0
No 2 has address 0x7fff5db122b0
No 3 has address 0x7fff5db122b0
No 4 has address 0x7fff5db122b0
```

Anyone has a clue for this?

Comment: `&new_node` --> `new_node` : `new_node` hold retrun value of `malloc`. `&new_node` is address of `new_node`, not retrun value of `malloc`.

Comment: You need to take the time to appreciate the difference between a pointer and a pointee. What holds and address, and what is at that address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're printing `&new_node`, the address of the pointer, not the pointer itself. In your case, `&new_node` is a constant value for one runtime.

If you want to print the pointer returned by `malloc()`, just supply the variable `new_node`, and cast it to `void *`.

That said, just a word of advice, despite being a snippet, you're missing out `free()` calls. It's causing memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing `&newnode`. This is the address of the pointer. This will always be the same.

What will change is the value in the pointer `newnode`.

If you print

```
printf("No %d has address %p\n", j, new_node);
```

You should get a different value each time, as expected.